# jQuery $.post not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

When I submit my form using $.post(), nothing happens at all. No error messages, no response, no nothing. It was working before, but it stopped working randomly.

This is my form:

```
<form id="login_form" class="drop-form" method="POST">
    <p class="lead">Sign in</p>
    <input class="form-control" name="user_email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" />
    <input class="form-control" name="user_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

and this is my jQuery:

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("core/login.php", $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        console.log('sent to core/login');
        // handle response
    }, 'json');
});
```

Chrome's browser console doesn't even show the "sent to core/login". What gives? Like I said, it was working before, and randomly it just stopped working.

Comment: check the network tab in chrome developer tools (same area as the console you referred to, just different tab) and look for the post to `login.php` and you should be able to see what headers are being sent and what (if any) response you're receiving from the server. The way you have your code, that `console.log` is part of the success callback and thus would not display in the console if the request failed for any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'sent to core/login' message would not appear until you get a success response back, so your problem is likely on the server side. The code you posted works fine client side, it's just not getting a response from 'core/login.php'

Comment: I checked the server response and found out PHP was spitting out a deprecated warning. Thanks!